# Limit Xquartz to One Monitor

Tags: macos, xorg, x11-forwarding, xquartz

I'm on OSX 10.7.4 in a multi monitor setup. I use X11Forwarding via SSH to work remotely. Both stock X11 and Xquartz X11 have no (obvious) setting to limit themselves to one monitor.

Is there a way I didn't find out?